# Java Nashorn - template strings

Tags: java, nashorn

Does Java Nashorn support JavaScript [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) ?

I get the following error when trying `` var a = `this is a \n multiline string \n ` ``:
 `javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:1:22 Expected an operand but found error`

Comment: it looks like template string are not still supported....they are using something called dustjs....check that out....http://www.leveluplunch.com/blog/2014/06/09/compile-load-render-dustjs-template-java-nashorn/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With Nashorn "scripting mode" (enabled by -scripting option with jjs and also -Dnashorn.args system property can be used for javax.script to set options), there is a Nashorn specific extension for multiline strings and string interpolation.

See also:

https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions#Nashornextensions-Multi-linestringliterals%28-scriptingmodeonly%29

As mentioned, ES6 features are being added to jdk9. You can enable es6 features (subset) using --language=es6 option